# Enqueue method that increases array size when queue is full

Tags: java, insert, queue

Currently I am working with queue and have been coding an enqueue method which adds elements to a queue. Whenever the queue is full I return a message that says the queue cannot insert any more elements. Now my task is to change the enqueue method in a way that doubles the array size limitation whenever trying to insert an element so that in theory the item will be added to the new expanded array and it will never fail into a full queue. How could I achieve this, anything is helpful.

Code

```
public void enqueue(Object newItem){
    if (!isFull()){
        back = (back+1) % QUEUE_SIZE;
        items[back] = newItem;
        count++;
        return;
    } else
        System.out.println("Trying to enqueue into full queue");
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, this is not "do my HW for me" kind of website, the best advice you'll get here is to try and do your HW by yourself. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create a new array with double size as `items`, then copy all your items from `items` and call your `enqueue` method again.

```
public void enqueue(Object newItem){
    if (!isFull()){
         ...
    } else {
        Object[] newItems = new Object[items.length * 2];
        copyFromTo(items, newItems);
        items = newItems;
        enqueue(newItem);
    }
}
```

Comment: For the copyFromTo would I have to create a new method?

Comment: That's right. Just iterate over `items` and assign values to `newItems`.